# Workfront AtTask API - Set Reviewers for Document

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Is it possible to set reviewers for a document using attask API? I can't find anything related in the documentation (which is pretty ugly BTW). The only thing I found is [this doc](http://api.proofhq.com/) for another Workfront API (SOAP) called Proof HQ, but I hope to be able to do it without using SOAP honestly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are trying to do it as a proof approval or just a regular approval. If it's just a regular approval, then you should be able make a POST and use the document approval object (DOCAPL). https://one.workfront.com/s/api-explorer